# graphene django with redis does not work?

Tags: django, caching, redis, graphql, graphene-python

I have a resolver and I gave it a key to save into `django-redis`, I can see the `key and value` inside redis but somehow the loading time is still the same.

If I am doing a regular `rest` it will work fine but somehow `graphql` doesn't seem to be working properly?

```
def resolve_search(self, info, **kwargs):
    redis_key = 'graphl_search'

    if cache.keys(redis_key):  # check if key exists, if do render the value
        print('using redis') # this will run the second time since key exists for 3600 seconds
        return cache.get(redis_key)

    # set redis
    print('set redis') # this will run the first time since they key does not exist yet
    my_model = Model.objects.filter(slug=kwargs.get('slug')).first()
    cache.set(redis_key, my_model, timeout=3600)
    return my_model
```

works properly and doesn't go into the rest of the block if `key` exists, but when I checked the time it would be the same.

- 1st time (5xx ms)
- 2nd time (5xx ms)

Am I doing something wrong or that is now how to should use `redis` with `graphql`?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions